# Removing salt and pepper effect

Tags: raster, grass-gis, classification, landsat

In a land cover raster (categorical map) that is a product of classified satellite image, what is the best way to remove "salt and pepper" effect from the image after classification. I am not interested in performing classification again, I am rather interested in a procedure that would use some kind of local functions. I use GRASS 7.

Comment: I have edited the question. I use GRASS 7.

Answer (score 5):

Majority Filter.  You can apply multiple runs to smooth the image.

Comment: please use longer answers that explain what it is, why it is the answer, and perhaps how to use it.

Comment: For this you may use r.neighbors. Another option is to vectorize with r.to.vect, then remove small areas with v.clean.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods that have been proposed to remedy this issue. The first one and the most obvious is to use Object-Based classification instead of Pixel-Based classification. This is more prevalent when the image you are classifying is very high resolution (sub-meter-resolution images for instance) and your area of interest is very heterogeneous (urban areas for instance).

Other techniques include the application of a  simple majority filter to the classified image or performing a further reclassification step within a moving window of fixed size.

My preferred method is the one proposed by Yuehong Chen et. al. (2018), a method he called "IPOC"(Integration of Pixel-Based and Object-Based Classifications). Please check the paper (it's open-access) and I guarantee you'll like the technique.